# Vue.js and Jest => Test suite failed to run ReferenceError: __GLOBAL is not defined

Tags: vue.js, jestjs

apiservice:
export const APIServer = axios.create({
baseURL: (**GLOBAL.baseURL || 'http:**___******') + '/******/v1',
^
});

When I am trying to test my component, my component has api service import and in my api service we defined a global baseurl(You can see in upper code),

When I try to run test my component I am getting error like (ReferenceError: __GLOBAL is not defined)

Comment: You need to provide any things from environment that the app relies on. If it's global var, you need to mock window.__GLOBAL. It's rarely a good idea to do real requests in Jest tests, one of ways to avoid this is to mock axios, this way you probably wouldn't have this error any way

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.